# Bandwidth of a DAC

Tags: pwm, clock, dac, bandwidth

Could anybody specify what does this bandwidth means in DAC PWM?

[image]
Source: [Designing high-performance PWM DACs for field transmitters](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt795/slyt795.pdf) (page 2)

The bandwidth of a DAC?

Answer (score 0):

\$f_C\$ is the cutoff frequency of the filter that you have to put in the circuit to smooth out the PWM signal - see top of figure 3 where there is a small block diagram.

\$f_{CLK}\$ is the frequency of the clock that controls the timing of the PWM signal. See figure 4. (The C in figure 4 is not the C in \$f_C\$, but the clock is the same clock in \$f_{CLK}\$)